# Validating codecov using curl throws error: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: curl, codecov

```
curl --data-binary @codecov.yml https://codecov.{my.url.something}/validate
```

This is the error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

What I've tried:

1. Reinstall curl using `brew install curl`
2. Reimported all the internal certificates

I still got this error after several tries, this is a stupid mistake:

When I type: `which curl`
It shows a curl command under another application, instead of `/usr/bin/curl` (mac). 
So in case of anyone who got this error, hopefully, it'll be helpful.